# Can someone give me a hint to this question concerning $\sum_{i=1}^n |x-i|$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, summation

Find the smallest positive integer $n$ for which
$|x − 1| + |x − 2| + |x − 3| + · · · + |x − n| \geq 2022$
for all real numbers $x$.

I don't think I can combine any of these terms, right? So I started by changing the equation into the sum of an arithmetic series, but I don't think that does anything.

$$\sum_{i=1}^n |x-i| = \frac{n}{2}(|x-1|+|x-n|) \ge 2022$$

I'm not sure how to go from here, any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Useless title... as it could apply to *EVERY* question ever posed on this site.

Comment: @bnkgfh Welcome to Math SE. FYI, using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%7Cx-1%7C%2B%7Cx-2%7C%2B...%2B%7Cx-n%7C%5Cge%202022%24%2C%20OR%20content%3Asmallest%2C%20OR%20content%3Ainteger&p=1), I found the AoPS thread [Absolute values](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c4h1568526p9617466), with this being the same as your problem except it uses $2016$ on the RHS instead of $2022$. Nonetheless, the approach to use is basically the same. ...

Comment: @bnkgfh (cont.) There were also several posts listed with somewhat similar problems, e.g., [Prove:$|x-1|+|x-2|+|x-3|+\cdots+|x-n|\geq n-1$](/q/439745) here, as well as the AoPS threads [Lots of Absolute values](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c4h1712470p11049312) and [A problem](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c3h1807679p12028073).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: to minimize the sum, you want an $x$ that minimizes the distance from $1, 2, \dots, n$: intuitively, what does this $x$ have to be?

> It should be
>  \begin{align} x &= \frac{n+1}{2}, \end{align}
>  the average of $1, 2, \dots, n$.

Then, compute the value of the sum at this $x$.

> For $n = 2k + 1$, the sum is $2 \sum_{m=1}^k m = k(k+1)$. For $n = 2k$, the sum is $2 \sum_{m=1}^{k} \left(m - \frac{1}{2}\right) = k^2$.

Then compute when those values are $\geq 2022$.

> In particular, since $44 \cdot 45 < 2022 < 45^2$, we see that we should pick $n = 90$.

Answer (score 1):

The expression given takes the smallest of its values when x is chosen to be $\frac{n}{2}$. We care about its smallest value since we want $n$ to have the smallest value which makes the expression greater than or equal to $2022$.

For odd $n$, we have $x = \frac{n+1}{2}$ and for even $n$, we have $x = \frac{n}{2}$. This will give us a sum of $$\left(\frac{n}{2}-1\right)+\left(\frac{n}{2}-2\right)+\left(\frac{n}{2}-3\right)+...+2+1+0+1+2+3+...+\left(\frac{n}{2}-1\right)+\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)$$ for any even $n$.

> Since we have $n$ terms the summation becomes $$\frac{n^2}{2}-2\cdot\left(\frac{n}{2}\cdot\frac{\frac{n}{2}+1}{2}\right)+\frac{n}{2}=\frac{n^2}{2}-\left(\frac{n^2+2n}{4}\right)+\frac{n}{2}=\frac{n^2}{4} \geq 2022$$ $+\frac{n}{2}$ is because we subtracted $\frac{n}{2}$ twice by multiplying $\left(\frac{n}{2}\cdot\frac{\frac{n}{2}+1}{2}\right)$ by $2$, but it occurs only once.